# Unable to drop constraint

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

On dropping a unique `constraint`, following error occurs,

> ORA-04098: trigger 'SYS.XDB_PI_TRIG' is invalid and failed re-validation

Having no permission to recompile this `trigger`.

What could be the problem here and is there any way we can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution to this,
The XDB Schema is invalid for the Database. So we are unable to drop any objects in this Database. So making the XDB schema valid, has solved this problem.

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This error reflects a compilation/authorization failure for a mentioned trigger. This trigger was invalid so failed to be retrieved for execution. You can run

```
SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER SYS.XDB_PI_TRIG;
```

in order to have a bigger picture of that error.

Trigger may need to be recompiled. Running:

```
alter trigger SYS.XDB_PI_TRIG compile
```

will recompile this trigger.
Common case is when user has privileges only to run and not change respective triggers. In that case you may need to recompile the Trigger as SYSDBA.

Comment: It shows error in a function, SYS.IS_VPD_ENABLED; on getting the error again from the same function. Error in the function is, 4/43           PLS-00421: circular synonym 'PUBLIC.DBMS_XDBZ'
0/0            PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is no SYSDBA privilege assigned for the user, am using. Do we have any other way to solve this?

Comment: If you try to connect let's say as SYS you can try connect SYS/<password> as SYSDBA

Answer (score 0):

I wouldthink that you may be dropping a primary key check what constraint your dropping. if your dropping a pk and its being used as a foreign key then this would invalidate the trigger.

Comment: Hi.. the constraint, am trying to drop is an unique constraint. The table has another primary key.

Comment: what is it constraining ?

Comment: Unique constraints can be used in place of a table primary key in a foreing key constraint.  Consider the followng [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/38c0c/2) where attempting to insert the second record in tab2 fails.